# Refrence Spring Beans Generated From an Interface in XML Bean Definition

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-3, spring-annotations

I have some code that generates a class from an interface. I need to reference that interface in a Spring XML configuration. Is there a Spring 3 annotations I can use on the interface such that I can reference the generated implementation using `<constructor-arg ref="myBeanInterface"/>`?

I can reference it  using `<constructor-arg value="com.mysite.myBeanInterface"/>`, however I want to refrence a bean name instead of an explicit class.

***Details:** The beans are generated by an extension of AbstractFactoryBean. I do not have access to the bean generating code.*

Answer (score 0):

Use the name of your factory bean. If you have something like:

```
<bean id="myBean class="MyBeanInterfaceFactoryBean>
    ...
</bean>
```

Then to inject the bean that was generated by the factory bean, just use `myBean`.